# Compatibility between Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Tags: windows-7, sql-server, visual-studio, windows-10-upgrade

I receive the free update from Microsoft for **Windows 10**. At the moment I'm using **Windows 7 Ultimate**. I have several question, for which I can't find anything in google or at least my search words was bad.

> - Is the update going to format my **C drive**.
> - Is it possible bugs to appear on the update and corrupt the current Windows. What happen if any problem appears on the update.
> - Is there possibility programs, which worked on Windows 7 to be not working on Windows 10. I have interest in programs like **Visual
>     Studio 2010/2013, SQL Management Studio 2005/2012**. Some
>     resource(forum, other site) which gives a list about programs which
>     are not working on windows 10 will be nice too.

I'm asking because I don't have the time to install everything from scratch if any problem appears.

Comment: Your post contains too many separate questions. This is not a good fit for our Q&A format, so please create separate posts for each distinct issue you have. See also: [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not format your C drive. The first installation is only an upgrade. Afterwards you can choose to reset for a clean install. If you reset, you can even choose to keep your files and programs. Just upgrading will not format anything though.

Something could always go wrong during the upgrade. My laptop is currently in a strange state from not being able to complete upgrade. Make sure you do backups of anything you need or make a system image.

Visual Studio 2013 will work on Windows 10, even [side by side with VS2015](http://nakedalm.com/installing-visual-studio-2015-side-side-2013-windows-10/). As for other programs, you will have to search online or try it yourself.

Comment: Information about VS2015 was helpful, I will read about it. I will wait some time if someone have more information, if not I will I will accept your answer. Thanks for the explanation.